# Logstash JSON Grok filter issue

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I have squid proxies setup to send JSON formatted logs to Elastic via Logstash.  I am trying to use GROK filtering to parse the logs.  The filter works in the Kiabana Grok Debugger but complains with the following error when I restart Logstash

```
Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:squid_logs,
 :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"
{\", \",\", \"]\" at line 10, column 62 (byte 137) after filter {\n  grok {\n    match => {\n 
       \"message\" => [ \"%{IPV4:vendor_ip}\", \"%{WORD:message}\"", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", 
"org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in `initialize'", 
"org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", 
"/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in `initialize'", 
"/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", 
"/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:389:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

I have the following GROK filter

```
"%{IPV4:vendor_ip}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{IPV4:clientip}", "%{WORD:message}": "%
{DATA:timestamp}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{WORD:verb}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{DATA:request}", "%
{WORD:message}": "%{URIPATHPARAM:path}"
```

In the Kibana Grok Debugger the filter works fine against a message like the following:

```
{ "vendor_ip": "x.x.x.x", "clientip": "x.x.x.x", "timestamp": "2021-04-09T13:58:38+0000", 
"verb": "GET", "request": "https://domain", "path": "/somepath", "httpversion": "HTTP/1.1", 
"response": 200, "bytes": 2518042, "referer": "-", "useragent": "Microsoft BITS/7.8", 
"request_status": "HIER_DIRECT", "hierarchy_status": "HIER_DIRECT" }
```

Logstash config below:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5045
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => {
        "message" => [ "%{IPV4:vendor_ip}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{IPV4:clientip}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{DATA:timestamp}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{WORD:verb}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{DATA:request}", "%{WORD:message}": "%{URIPATHPARAM:path}" ]
    }
  }
}


output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["x.x.x.x:9200"]
    index => "squid_logs"
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that this has already been answered fantastically, but just for the record... the logstash config above is invalid... specifically, your grok's `message` setting is a malformed. Better would be something like `[ "\{ \"vendor_ip\": \"${IPV4:vendor_ip}\", \"clientip\": \"%{IPV4:clientip}\",`... etc

Comment: Thank you for the comment at least.  It's good to know that the syntax was off even though grok debugger accepted it.

Comment: I normally use [grokdebug](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) instead of the kibana builtin.. mostly because it was the first tool I found.. seems to have less of these issues but YMMV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing a json message using the grok filter is the wrong approach, there is no need to do this and it will be a lot of work since you will need to escape all the double quotes in the message or you will get configuration errors, which is your case.

Use the [json](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html) filter to parse json messages

Just use this in your pipeline:

```
filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a lot simpler than what I was trying to do.